# ä ö ü not shown in json php

Tags: php, json, special-characters

when I am posting a text wie ä ü ö into $text1 or $text2 the json_encode($response); gives me null. when i echo my inputtet text, it returns the right value with ö ü ä ... what can I do so my json_encode echo also returns value with ä ü ö and not null

```
$response["test"] = array();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        // temp user array
        $test= array();
        $test["text1"] = $text1;
        $test["text2"] = $text2;
        +
echo $text1;


        array_push($response["test"], $news);
        echo $response;
    }

    $response["success"] = 1;


   echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: + was typing mistake^^

Answer (score 1):

```
echo json_encode('ä ö ü');
```

yields

```
"\u00e4 \u00f6 \u00fc"
```

Which are just the escaped versions of those characters. When you print them out it should look fine.

Your code example, however, doesn't make much sense. Where are `$news`, `$text1` and `$text2` defined? Why do you have a random `+` in the middle of your loop? What's going on with the indentation? What does `var_dump($response)` spit out? If you have jibberish in your response array, that might be why you're getting back null.

Also, check [json_last_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) or [json_last_error_msg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) if you're using >=5.5

Comment: thats only a example code with no sense^^ i am posting the texts into my mysql.. utf8 , they are stored as ü ö ... i can see that in phpmyadmin - in this question i retrieve the data from mysqli

i could fix that problem with:

mysqli_set_charset($this->conn,"utf8");

however that worked some days ago also without this... i think i changed something but I dont remember, because that also worked without "mysqli_set_charset($this->conn,"utf8");" 

ah + was my mistake

Answer (score 0):

All things you throw at json_encode() must actually be encodable, for strings that is only the case when they are valid UTF-8 encoding. They still won't show up as plain umlauts in the output though, for that there's an additional flag to prevent the escaping of non-ASCII letters.

Note:
 * The actual PHP version matters, the capabilities changed between 5.3, 5.4 and 5.5.
 * There is a function to retrieve encoding-related error information, just read the documentation to familiarize yourself with the API.